# Django Admin with choices raising validation error

Tags: django

This is my first project with Django and I need help how to fix the error. I want to have a dropdown menu to select in the first field the day, and into the second field to select the month. I can display them, however, I'm getting errors when I try to create an event. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    months_of_year = ((0, 'January'), (1, 'February'), (2, 'March'), (3, 'April'), (4, 'May'), (5, 'June'), (6, 'July'), (7, 'August'), (8, 'September'), (9, 'October'), (10, 'November'), (11, 'December'))
    days_of_month = ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8), (9,9), (10,10), (11,11), (12,12), (13,13), (14,14), (15,15), (16,16), (17,17), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20), (21,21), (22,22), (23,23), (24,24), (25,25), (26,26), (27,27), (28,28), (29,29), (30,30), (31,31))
    month = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=months_of_year)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=days_of_month)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please add your __view__, __form__, __template__. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to save ***integer*** value in the **`CharField()`**.

I would suggest changing the `CharField` to **`IntegerField(...)`** as,

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # rest of the field
    month = models.IntegerField(choices=months_of_year)
    days = models.IntegerField(choices=days_of_month)
```

---

Apart from that, you can ***clean your model choices*** using the [**calender**--(PyDoc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module of Python as,

```
import calendar


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    months_of_year = [(i, calendar.month_name[i]) for i in range(1, 13)]
    days_of_month = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 32)]
    month = models.IntegerField(choices=months_of_year)
    days = models.IntegerField(choices=days_of_month)
```

Comment: for months is returning number, how can I take the name?